# In a Bash scrtipt, how can i check if the python version is above some value?

Tags: python, shell

I'd like to ensure that the python version that is installed on the current user machine is above some value.

Is there something more graceful than parsing the output of "python --version"?

Comment: You could write actual Python code to do that. Why bash if you already have Python installed? Otherwise, what's difficult about parsing that output?

Comment: **python --version** is the right way to do it. There's nothing ungraceful about that